# Select and weigh questions on a reading assessment

Tags: machine-learning, lasso, psychometrics

I am a phd student in computer science and as such I am the goto guy for anything "mathy" in the cross discipline research group to which I belong. I have recently been given an assignment at work I'm struggeling a bit with.

Around 500 students have been given 3 tests each assessing their reading comprehension on 3 different texts. That is, each student has completed all three tests. Each test consist of 10-13 questions which can be either right or wrong.

My problem now is to try to select the best subset of questions for each test and assign weights to these questions. I've heard the terms Item Response Theory, Rasch modeling, and Chronbach's Alpha but my background in psychometric statistics consist basically of hearing these terms mentioned once or twice.

Are any of these methods applicable to my problem? Which should I choose?

A approach I've tried based on my current "sphere of comfort" is the following:

First I calculate each student's total score (on the interval 0 to 1 as the ratio of correct answers) on all three tests. I then do Lasso regression over each of the tests, using cross-validation to select the value of the penalty coefficient, to select and assign weights to the questions. As a student getting 0 correct answers on a test should get 0 points on that same test, I apply Lasso without an intercept term. After a quick trial run I can't see anything obviously wrong.

How naive and silly is this approach? Am I missing anything obvious? Does it relate in any way to established methods in psychometrics?

Comment: This reads a bit like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). It might be easier to answer a question about X than Y. (You're free to leave it as is, but it's often the case that asking about the original problem is more productive)

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question somewhat. I'm still interested in feedback on my approach but I made that more of a second priority.